# What is a descent way to calculate nsdate timeintervalsince the past 30 days in Swift?

Tags: swift, date

I'm trying to figure out the best way to calculate 30 days ago using NSDate or Date.  I understand that time intervals are in seconds so I've tried the following:

I used a time conversion website to get 30 days in seconds [Time Conversion for 30 days](https://www.convertunits.com/from/30+days/to/seconds) which produced 2592000 seconds.  After that I implemented the following in Swift:

```
let since30 = Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: -2592000)
        print(since30)
```

The problem is that today's date is 9/24/2018 but the console prints out 2018-08-26 00:21:58 +0000 which is off by a couple of days.  Is my conversion off is there a better way to calculate 30 days ago using the Date class?

Comment: Is it exactly 30 days or a month that you want to subtract from today?

Comment: 30 days...is what I have accurate?

Comment: `let since30 = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: Date())`

Comment: @LeoDabus How did you come up with this so quickly?  Is it the amount of experience you've had with dates?  What was your process?

Comment: I have been coding in Swift and active on SO for more than 4 years already. It is a really steep learning curve but you will get through it naturally. Swift it is very powerful and intuitive.